# How do I remove the language param from the URL for the default language?

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 3.4 project I need to use localisation with a few languages. I would like to make URLs like the following:

- `mysite.com/path/page/1` (for default language = 'en')
- `mysite.com/de/path/page/1` (for 'de' language)
- `mysite.com/fr/path/page/1` (for 'fr' language)
- etc...

So I would like to add the language code into URL, but not for the default one.

In the same time I would rather to not overcomplicate URL creation in Twig templates. The perfect scenario would be to not change the `path(...)` calls at all.

My idea was to add the following to `config.yml`:

`parameters:
  locale: en
  locale_url: ''
framework:
  default_locale: "%locale%"`

and the following to `routing.yml`:

`mybundle:
  resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /{_locale}/
  requirements:
    _locale: de|fr|
  defaults: {_locale: %locale_url%}`

Then I would change both `locale` and `locale_url` on the `onKernelRequest` event.

The URL generation with the above code works great. The only problem is that I cannot change the value of `locale_url` in the runtime, as the following error is thrown:
`Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.`

I found that using `symfony/config` component would be helpful, but I couldn't find anything suitable in its documentation.

How do I remove the language param from the URL for the default language?

Comment: You could consider using the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) since it has this option as described [here](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration).

Comment: @AlanT., I just checked the bundle you mentioned. It works like a charm! Thank you for your quick help!

Comment: For those who try to use the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) with Varnish - there is an undocumented config option, called `jms_i18n_routing.cookie.enabled`. Setting that to `false` will prevent the bundle from setting `hl` cookie, which then will improve Varnish caching. But that will only work for the scenario similar to mine.